# Как сделать так, чтобы после ввода имени был переход на другую сцену.(Unity)

Tags: unity3d

Здравия! Возникла такая проблема, что хочу сделать после ввода конкретного имени переход на конкретную сцену, где будет продолжаться диалог, так сказать, по другой ветви истории, но не очень понимаю, как сделать правильней код, чтобы все работало. (прим. Игрок ввел имя Mari и после этого его кидает на сцену с названием forMari и там продолжается запланированный под это имя диалог).
Сам вопрос: Как правильно написать код, чтобы после ввода имени преходило на нужную сцену?
Буду очень рада, если кто-то сможет мне помочь. Я совсем начинающая..
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Считать имя и загрузить сцену, основываясь на этом имени. Исходя из вашего вопроса, не совсем понятно что вам непонятно. Если непонятно как загружать сцены - [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), если непонятно всё - [юнитивские курсы](https://learn.unity.com/courses)

Comment: @KOTlK, упустила важную часть вопроса, извиняюсь. Я примерно представляю как это должно происходить, но моя проблема заключена в правильном составлении кода. Буду рада, если сможете помочь.

Comment: Если вы совсем новичок, тогда вам пока рано задумываться о правильности кода, вы все равно не поймете смысл большинства советов. Просто самостоятельно пишите код, в этом будет больше пользы, чем читать советы. Если что-то не получается, тогда ищите похожие проблемы в интернете, в крайнем случае пишите сюда, прикладывайте код и вам все разъяснят. Максимум, что могу посоветовать - не давать игроку возможность выбора посредством ввода какой-то строки. Лучше выводить возможные имена как список. Не будет ситуаций, когда игрок ввел что-то не то и игра вылетела, т.к. это было не предусмотрено.